# How to define a JNDI Datasource on Undertow?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource, jndi

I have a running Spring application that already works on Weblogic and JBoss, and I'm adding the option to run it by itself with Spring Boot.

As it has a Java EE architecture, it has a container-managed datasource that is looked up by a JNDI name, and I wanted to keep it that way.

I see that Spring Boot has the ability to use a EE container called Undertow, that it turns out to be the Wildfly EE engine.

I've done A LOT of research on how to define this JNDI Datasource in Undertow with config files and stuff, but I can't find any documentation on that on Undertow's website and neither on WildFly documentation.

Has someone already done that? I need to know how to define this Datasource with a config file or something.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-a-jndi-datasource

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/DataSource+configuration

Comment: @AntonNovopashin Thank you, Anton. The first link is the easy part, my app is already configured that way. But the second link is related to the Wildfly configuration, not the standalone Undertow configuration. I need to know the equivalent for a `standalone.xml` in Undertow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think Undertow supports that - it's just a web server, nothing else, and very far from being a JEE container. Wildfly, on the other hand, is a JEE container and it uses Undertow as a web engine and builds up other JEE stuff around it.

Here's a quote from [Undertow's official documentation](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.3.0/index.html#architecture-overview):

> On thing that makes Undertow unique is that it has no concept of a global container. Instead an Undertow server is assembled by the embedding application. This makes Undertow extremely flexible, and the embedding application can basically just pick the parts that they need, and assemble them in whatever way makes sense.
>
> **An Undertow server is basically composed of three things, one (or more) XNIO worker instance, one or more connectors, and a handler chain to handle incoming requests.**

Comment: Unfortunatelly, you're right :/ But thanks for the enlightening, anyway.

Comment: I was also looking for an embedded servlet container and managed to run Undertow only to find out that it doesn't have any JNDI, which is not part of the servlet spec I just found out. I guess I'll try embedded tomcat...